# It keeps saying my function is not defined in python

Tags: python

I am taking a intro to computer programming class and in it we use python.

My assignment is to Write a program named paint.py that will determine the cost of painting the walls of a shed with a rectangular floor. Assume the shed has no windows and that paint costs $40 per gallon. One gallon covers 300 square feet. Prompt the user to enter the dimensions of the shed. Use a function named paint_cost that takes the user inputs as arguments and returns the cost of painting the walls of the shed. Express the cost in currency format.

I have tried really hard on thinking how to do it.  I have researched and read the chapter over and over again in my python book.  So if anyone can please help me.

```
def paint_cost(price):
    return (dimen / 300) * 40
def main():
    dimen = input('Enter the dimensions of the shed: ')
    print('Your cost of painting will be $', paint_cost(price))
main()
```

Comment: If I run this code, it doesn't tell me the function isn't defined. It does tell me `NameError: name 'price' is not defined`. `price` quite obviously isn't defined anywhere, and is probably not meant to be a function. (This, by the way, is exactly why you should post the actual error message, not just describe it.)

Comment: Actually, if you fix two _other_ errors, then you _will_ get an error about the function `retun` not being defined, because that typo happens to make your return statement look like an expression with a call to a function named `retun` in it…

Comment: @Marius, meant `retun`

Comment: Also, not related to your code, but you don't specify to the user that the  dimensions they're entering are in square feet. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors in your original code:

- Line 2: `retun` should be `return`
- Remove `price` from the `paint_cost` function, because you are calculating it on line 2.
- Replace it with `dimen`

.

```
def paint_cost(dimen):
    cost = (dimen / 300) * 40
    return cost
def main():
    dimen = int(input('Enter the dimensions of the shed: '))
    print 'Your cost of painting will be $ %s' % str(paint_cost(dimen))
main()
```

Comment: True, but he isn't even getting that far.

Comment: Wow I did not see that, but it still says:

NameError: name 'price' is not defined

Comment: @Redblaster13: Yeah, as Padraic points out, there are at least 3 major errors in your code; it's hard to fault anyone for not being able to guess which one you're going to see first without running it… With a slight change, this one would be a `SyntaxError` and prevent you from getting to the `NameError`…

Comment: Im brand new to functions sorry, can you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Yeah, so you know how you are telling `paint_cost` to take in the `price`? It should really take in the `dimen`, right? because you're calculating the `paint_cost` based on the `dimen`. The price is fixed to $40.

Comment: There are also some typos (`SyntaxError`s) in your code. If you use what I put above, it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is closer to what you are trying to do:

```
def paint_cost(dimen):
    return (dimen / 300.) * 40  # calculates cost based on dimension
def main():
    dimen = int(input('Enter the dimensions of the shed: ')) ]  # cast input as an integer
    print('Your cost of painting will be ${}'.format(paint_cost(dimen)))# pass the dimensions to paint_cost and print using `str.format`
main()
```

errors in your original code:

`retun` should be `return` so a syntax error

`(dimen / 300) * 40` `dimen` only exists in the `main` function so an undefined error

`paint_cost(price)` price is not defined, so another undefined error

Comment: Ah thank you so much didn't realize I should put dimen as the parameter.

Answer (score -1):

In your line:

```
print('Your cost of painting will be $', paint_cost(price))
```

`price` has not been defined.

Usually Python will give a good description of what's wrong, as it did for me here when I ran this:

```
NameError: global name 'price' is not defined
```

There are other problems, but work your way through, paying particular attention to the tracebacks.